# Regex for no single quote and newline character in between single quotes

Tags: regex

so far I have this **'.[^ \n']*'(?!')** with a negative look ahead after the last qoute

Unfortunately, this does allow ''' (three single quotes).

The regex should match these strings

- 'abc'
- 'abc#@$%^xyz'

The regex shouldn't match these strings

- '\n'
- 'abc#'@$%^xyz'
- '''
- '

My current regex is looking at negative precedes for a single quote. I am trying to find a way to make it more generalized so if doesn't match if it has odd number of single qoutes.

Answer (score 0):

If your patterns occur always alone in a line, you could use this:

```regex
^'[^\n']*'$
```

If you want to find matching pairs of single quotes in a bigger text, I think regex is not the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
^'[^\n']*(?:'[^\n']*')*[^\n']*'$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `'` Match a single quote
- `[^\n']*` Match 0+ chars other than a newline or a single quote
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `'[^\n']*'` Match from  `'` to `'` without matching newlines in between
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `[^\n']*` Match 0+ chars other than a newline or a single quote
- `'` Match a single quote
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bMugjA/1).